# Gunicorn 500'ing on POST to Flask app

Tags: python-2.7, flask, virtualenv, gunicorn

Here's the Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods = ['POST'])
def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        message = request.form['message']

        flash(name)
        flash(email)
        flash(message)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key='a;sldfjka;oeiga;lbneas; biaweag'
    app.run()
```

Here's the template I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <form action="/contact" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <input type="text" name="email" />
            <textarea name="message"> </textarea>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form> 
        <ul>
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
            <li><h3> {{ message }} </h3></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the `gunicorn` command line I use to serve it:

```
gunicorn --error-logfile err.log --access-logfile access.log \
--log-level debug -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --debug -w 4 wsgi:app
```

It serves the GET request for the template just fine.  However, when I actually POST the form, it 500's out.  Here's the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Server: gunicorn/0.17.2
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 21:57:25 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 291
```

Here's what shows up in the gunicorn logs:

```
==> err.log <==
2013-03-21 17:12:38 [10092] [DEBUG] POST /contact

==> access.log <==
"127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2013:17:12:38] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 500 291 \
"http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) \
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"
```

Works fine when I serve it using Flask's built in dev server.

Mah brain tells me that this is something reeeeally simple that I'm just missing.  Guh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I defined the secret_key in the name == main block.  Gunicorn was choking because the app didn't have said key, which it needs to handle form submissions.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = #...
```

That line needs to be... anywhere else, so long as it gets evaluated when the script is run by gunicorn.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = #...
```

I think it's worth pointing out that if I had any kind of decent logging set up, I would have caught this little screw up right away.

Comment: Thanks for bothering to post the resolution, I had exactly the same issue and this resolved it instantly. Probably saved me hours.